# Installing "Make" for Windows

Tags: windows-8, make

I would like to install "Make" for Windows 8.

I'm currently working on NodeJS app that will be run on a Windows server and previously I have used NodeJS in a Linux environment. I need make to run my Mocha tests.

Can anyone help me out as my google-fu seems to be failing me tonight.

(I saw something about setting Cygwin but would like to avoid that route)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MinGW or MSYS, but you may be better off by just setting up a VM with Linux.

Edit to add: Another option is GnuWin32

Comment: The app needs to run on a Windows 8 server, no choice :-/

Comment: Then good luck with MinGW, MSYS or GnuWin32. GnuWin32 will also bring other unix utilities which you may need to successfully run the make file.